# what money format should I use for stripe payments

Tags: php

here is the code I have so far, the price was for $100, but its charging my users 1 dollar instead.

```
    <?php 
      $cost = "100.00";
    ?>

    <form action="" method="POST">
    <script                                      
    src="https://checkout.stripe.com/checkout.js" class="stripe-button"
    data-key="my key"
    data-image="/square-image.png"
    data-name="product name"
    data-description="some description"
    data-email="myemail@email.com"
    data-amount="<?php echo $cost; ?>">
    </script>
    </form>
```

Comment: I don't know what's your goal but if your code is echoed in php then "$100" is maybe treated as a variable because $ is the notion for variables, try '$100' instead

Comment: We have no idea what you're doing with `data-amount="100"`

Comment: the money format needs to be handled in php, and I will put the amount in there instead with the amount variable. the $100 isn't treated as a variable because it is not in the php tags.

Answer (score 1):

Stripe for US accepts amounts in cents

https://support.stripe.com/questions/which-zero-decimal-currencies-does-stripe-support

So 100 * 100 (100 dollars * 100 cents in 1 dollar) = 10000

Answer (score 0):

Use this :-

```
<form action="/charge" method="POST">
  <script
    src="https://checkout.stripe.com/checkout.js" class="stripe-button"
    data-key="pk_test_6pRNASCoBOKtIshFeQd4XMUh"
    data-image="/img/documentation/checkout/marketplace.png"
    data-name="Stripe.com"
    data-description="2 widgets"
    data-amount="2000">
  </script>
</form>
```

[Click here for more info](https://stripe.com/docs/checkout#integration-simple)

Comment: what is happening, is the value I have coming through the variable, is 100.00 what needs to happen is I need to remove the decimal for stripe payments, because when it rounds, the amount is 100.

Comment: Use round() php function to get only round value. follow link                                                                 http://php.net/manual/en/function.round.php

Comment: the round value is useless, because the round value is 100, I need the full amount with out the decimal.

Comment: I added the value with a variable so you can get a better idea of whats happening.. the value is already 100.00 and i need the full cost without the decimal. edits... got it working by simply doing a str_replace on the value to remove the decimal.

Answer (score 0):

The amount you want to charge needs to be in cents, not dollars. Also, the $ sign is needs to be removed since it is being set as data-currency, using ISO codes (with USD being the default).

```
 <form action="" method="POST">
    <script                                      
    src="https://checkout.stripe.com/checkout.js" class="stripe-button"
    data-key="my key"
    data-image="/square-image.png"
    data-name="product name"
    data-description="some description"
    data-currency="USD"
    data-email="myemail@email.com"
    data-amount="10000">
    </script>
    </form>
```

Answer (score 0):

I figured out how to fix it by doing a str_replace on the amount value, so I can get the full amount with out the decimal.